# Using arrays inside if conditions

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

This code is supposed to simulate the ticketing system of an airport.

This code has 3 different classes: AirlineTicket, which contains the constructor, accessors and mutators of the objects created in this program; AirlineTicketTester, which creates an object and an array, and uses a method inside the same class to fill that array with "passengers"; TicketOrganizer has two methods, but only one of them matters: `canBoardTogether()`. What this method should do is check if a passenger in the array can board with the following passenger. The condition for this is that both passengers need to have the same Boarding Group and Row (both attributes of the AirlineTicket class). However, this method is not working correctly, it doesn't return the correct passengers that can board together.

What can I do to correct said method?
TicketOrganizer class

```
import java.util.*;
public class TicketOrganizer
{
    private ArrayList<AirlineTicket> tickets;
    
    public TicketOrganizer(ArrayList<AirlineTicket> ticket){
        this.tickets = ticket;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<AirlineTicket> getTickets(){
        return tickets;
    }
       
        }
        public String canBoardTogether(){
            String together = "";
            int counter = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i<tickets.size()-1; i++){
                if(tickets.get(i).getBoardingGroup() == 
                tickets.get(i+1).getBoardingGroup()&&tickets.get(i).getRow() == 
                tickets.get(i+1).getRow()){
                together = together + "Passenger " + i + " can board with Passenger " + (int)(i+1) + "\n";
                counter++;
            }
        } 
            if(counter == 0){
            return "There are no passengers with the same row and boarding group.";
            }
            
            return together;
        

    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post where the problem is? Nobody is gonna read 3 classes

Comment: What are the types of your ticket information? (String, int)?

Comment: The types of ticket information are int

Comment: Now that I see what you're trying to do I don't see a problem with your code.  You should print out the boarding and ticket info to ensure it is consistent with what you believe.

Comment: It would be good to see both the actual output along with the expected output, so that we could see what might be wrong.

Comment: @GustavoC  I ran your code and it worked.  Since you are using random data it may not always behave as you want.  And you need to add a getName() method to the AirlineTicket class.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are only comparing `tickets.get(i)` with `tickets.get(i+1)`, your code requires that tickets with the same boarding group and row will be *adjacent* in `tickets` list.

Unless tickets is sorted by boarding group and then row, your code won't necessarily find the matches you are expecting.

Try this before doing your search:

```
tickets.sort(comparing(AirlineTicket::getBoardingGroup).andThen(AirlineTicket::getRow));
```

Comment: We already covered that.  I made the same assumption.  They are adjacent.  The problem is that the data is  random so it won't always work as expected.

Comment: @WJS I see no coverage of this - the text "sort" is nowhere else on this page. Given OP's algorithm, pre-sorting is required - there's no getting around that.